# chrome cast on chrome not sending message

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

```
if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
  setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
}

function initializeCastApi() {
  var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
  var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
    sessionListener,
    receiverListener);
  chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
};

function sessionListener(e) {
  //this function doenot runs firsttime
  appendMessage('New session ID:' + e.sessionId);
  session = e;
  session.addUpdateListener(sessionUpdateListener); 
  session.addMessageListener(namespace, receiverMessage);
  console.log(receiverMessage);
}
```

`sessionListener()` function doenot gets called first time.when session get updaed it gets called.Why is it so?